# Does parseInt return a strict integer?

Tags: javascript, function, integer, rounding

My understanding was that javascript doesn't strictly speaking have an integer datatype, but I'm coming across a weird problem that's having me second guess myself.

I'm trying to build a simple custom rounding function using parseInt to drop extra decimal places, but the full function *always* returns an integer:

```
function round(num, places){
    return (parseInt(num*10^places) + 0.5)/10^places
}
```

For completeness, I'm using this function within another:

```
function convertDegrees(val, uom){
    if (uom === "celcius"){
    return round(val * 9/5 + 32, 2) + " degrees Fahrenheit"}
    else {
    return round((val - 32) * 5/9, 2) + " degrees Celcius"}
}
```

But I don't see what in that would cause the problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to raise something to an exponent which needs `**`  not `^` which is [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

```js
function round(num, places) {
  return (parseInt(num * 10 ** places) + 0.5) / 10 ** places
}

function convertDegrees(val, uom) {
  if (uom === "celcius") {
    return round(val * 9 / 5 + 32, 2) + " degrees Fahrenheit"
  } else {
    return round((val - 32) * 5 / 9, 2) + " degrees Celcius"
  }
}

console.log(convertDegrees(0, 'celcius'))
```

Comment: Or `Math.pow()` if your environment doesn't support the exponentiation operator.

Comment: Thanks for that comment @SamVK -- it sent me to MDN, I didn't know `**` wasn't universal.

Comment: Whoops! Ech, so much to learn, so little time to learn it, of course I'm dropping all sorts of bits as I go!